# как сделать чтобы header не двигался

Tags: css

Изменяю размер окна браузера, шапка двигается.
Как сделать, чтобы заголовок не перемещался?

вот код

```
header {
    float: left;
    background-color: #343434;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2%;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #59595a;
    position: fixed;

}
```

Comment: `position: fixed` для header?

Comment: куда записать php или css

Comment: Все стили должны храниться только в css. Вёрстка и стили вперемешку на одной странице, это скорее исключение.

Comment: Возможно. Лично я не до конца понимаю как и что у вас выглядит. Куда двигается и как должно выглядеть в идеале. Дополните вопрос примером кода, который у вас есть сейчас и **возможно** получите более развёрнутый ответ. Т.к. сейчас ваш вопрос похож на: "Помогите ничего не работает, что делать?" :)